# Exporting XML from Excel with CDATA tags

Tags: xml, excel, vba, export, cdata

I'm attempting to determine a simple and efficient process for exporting data from excel to XML, while wrapping certain fields in CDATA tags. I've gotten to the point where I have exported XML (using the process outlined [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/xml.html)), but I'm stuck on the best way to inject the CDATA tags to wrap certain field values. I've searched extensively, but have not identified a solution. I'd prefer NOT to include the actual CDATA tags in my excel data if possible.

Current XML Code Sample (abridged):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<product>
    <code>1</code>
    <searchEngineSupportPages>
        <searchEngineSupportPage locale="en_US">
            <siteSearchEngineSupports>
                <siteSearchEngineSupport siteCode="CH">
                    <urlValue>test-url</urlValue>
                    <title>Test Title</title>
                    <metaDescription>Test Desc</metaDescription>
                    <metaKeywords>keyword, test</metaKeywords>
                </siteSearchEngineSupport>
            </siteSearchEngineSupports>
        </searchEngineSupportPage>
    </searchEngineSupportPages>
</product>
</products>
```

Desired XML Code Sample (notice CDATA tags):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<product>
    <code>1</code>
    <searchEngineSupportPages>
        <searchEngineSupportPage locale="en_US">
            <siteSearchEngineSupports>
                <siteSearchEngineSupport siteCode="CH">
                    <urlValue>test-url</urlValue>
                    <title>Test Title</title>
                    <metaDescription><![CDATA[Test Desc]]></metaDescription>
                    <metaKeywords><![CDATA[keyword, test]]></metaKeywords>
                </siteSearchEngineSupport>
            </siteSearchEngineSupports>
        </searchEngineSupportPage>
    </searchEngineSupportPages>
</product>
</products>
```

Is there a simple and efficient method for ensuring the exported XML for specified fields is wrapped in CDATA tags? Is VBA a possibility?

I'm not attached to the process I'm using, so I'm open to other thoughts on how to collectively address, if there is a better way. I like the Excel XML export feature because its simple and it works. I'm not an XML/VBA guru, but I'm capable.

Thanks in advance!

======================================

**EDIT [July 15, 2015]:** Martijn was kind enought to provide an approach using XSLT, but wondering if there is something a little more streamlined that would accomplish this objective?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the folloing XSLT to do this job for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="metaDescription|metaKeywords">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Martijin - I took your code and created a file called Product_SEO_Export.xsl.I then added "<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Product_SEO_Export.xsl"?>" to my Product_SEO_Export.xml file. These are in same local folder. I open the XML file in Chrome and view source, but just see my original XML. In IE 11 I get an error "XML page cannot be displayed. Required attribute 'select' is missing." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are correct. I copied the wrong code. The right answer is now in the updated answer. I hope this works for you.

Comment: @Martijin - Thanks so much for the time and effort. Your corrected code works - in the sense that it is rendering plain text (e.g. 1 test-url      Test Title <![CDATA[Test Desc]]> <![CDATA[keyword, test]]>). However, I want to produce output similar to my desired xml code sample in the original question post. I will be taking the output XML and uploading to a CMS, which requires it to be in an XML format, with CDATA tags wrapping certain string fields. Wondering if this is the best method for accomplishing that objective?

Comment: If you take a look in the browsers DOM (e.g. using firebug in FireFox) you can see the XML takes the required format. I trust this will also function in your CMS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please indicate the answer as the selected answer,.